# I18nextProvider fallback to second default namespace

Tags: i18next, react-i18next

I have 2 components A and B with their own translation files, and a shared translation file that should be used as a fallback. How to get it to work with `I18nextProvider`?

Note that there is already a separate fallback translation file defined `fallbackNS: 'common'` and I **do not** want to add the shared file there, it must only be shared between these 2 components.

I tried this:

```
<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n} defaultNS={['A', 'shared']}>
  <A />
</I18nextProvider>

<I18nextProvider i18n={i18n} defaultNS={['B', 'shared']}>
  <B />
</I18nextProvider>
```

But it would always try to get the translation from the namespace in the first element in the array.

I don't understand what's the point of allowing array as an argument in this case? When would any other than the first element be used in localization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures I find the answer as soon as I speak it out in public...

`const {t} = useTranslation(undefined, {nsMode: 'fallback'});`

Basically nsMode has to be fallback. Now just to figure out how to make it the default.

EDIT: to set default:

```
react: {
  nsMode: 'fallback'
}
```